# Event Ticketing solution that works with Dynamics CRM

Tags: crm

Does anyone know of any event ticketing solutions that work with Dynamics CRM?

I'm trying to find something that will work well for a non-profit that doesn't have a great deal of money to spend.

This one http://www.crminnovation.com/crm-solutions/event2crm.htm# for example works in conjunction with Eventbrite. Unfortunately it costs $795 for a start-up fee, and then requires and annual subscription of $1,495. I believe that's far out of their price range.

The solution could work with Eventbrite, Ticketleap, or any other common ticketing services, as long as it can also pull data into Dynamics CRM.

(Feel free to offer any solution you know of, regardless of price--other solutions may be useful to people in the future.)